# focus UV unwrap on high-detail area

Tags: python, uv, texture-baking

I have a set of objects.
Some of them have low-detail texture (`bakeSrc1`), some have high-detail one (`bakeSrc2`).

[image]

[image]

When I want to export them as a single `.obj` (for game), I always join them, unwrap, then use standard bake, the result is :-
[image]

Notice that the red one (`bakeSrc1`) get lot of UV-space just because it is big.
However, the blue high-detail brick (`bakeSrc2`), that actually want more, starves of UV-space.

How to guide uv unwraping to match level of detail of texture?

My random thought :-

- Create a floating-point ***custom property*** name `myLevelOfDetail=5` for `bakeSrc2` and `myLevelOfDetail=1` for `bakeSrc1` and make the UV unwrap recognize them?
- Create **vertex-color** / **vertex-group** with a certain name `myLevelOfDetail` with a custom value for each object that UV unwrap recognize them?
- I don't want to manually manage UV every time.
- The result must have only 1 UV map.
- I don't mind python approach, if it is needed.

Comment: Hi :). Just curious - why not adjust the UV manually? It will give you the best control.

Comment: @Jachym :: Thank.   The main cause is convenience.   I modify the `bakeSrc1/2/3` quite often.  Currently, whenever I do that, I can use python to auto-re-export them in 1 click.   I addict to such automation. (∩_∩)